# How to handle headers with merged cells in excel in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I Have this excel with merged cells for species.
[image]

I would like to have a data table with columns named Specie_1_Poitn1, Specie_1_Poitn2, .....

How can I do this?

I tried this, but it's not what I want

```
df = pd.read_excel("/content/drive/MyDrive/Pollens.xlsx", sheet_name="Jun")
species_pattern = "Specie_"
species_columns = [col for col in df.columns[2:] if species_pattern in str(col)]
species_columns
dfPollensJun = pd.read_excel("/content/drive/MyDrive/Pollens.xlsx",sheet_name="Jun",header = 1)
for i, species in enumerate(species_columns):
    columns = dfPollensJun.columns[i*6+2:(i+2)*6+1]
    novas_colunas = [f"{species}_{coluna}" for coluna in columns]
    dfPollensJun.rename(columns=dict(zip(columns, novas_colunas)), inplace=True)
dfPollensJun
```

And I got this

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 360 entries, 0 to 359
Data columns (total 20 columns):
 #   Column                       Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------                       --------------  -----         
 0   Data                         360 non-null    datetime64[ns]
 1   Hour                         360 non-null    object        
 2   Specie_1_Point_1             360 non-null    int64         
 3   Specie_1_Point_2             360 non-null    int64         
 4   Specie_1_Point_3             360 non-null    int64         
 5   Specie_1_Point_4             360 non-null    int64         
 6   Specie_1_Média               360 non-null    float64       
 7   Specie_1_Total               360 non-null    int64         
 8   Specie_2_Specie_1_Point_1.1  360 non-null    int64         
 9   Specie_2_Specie_1_Point_2.1  360 non-null    int64         
 10  Specie_2_Specie_1_Point_3.1  360 non-null    int64         
 11  Specie_2_Specie_1_Point_4.1  360 non-null    int64         
 12  Specie_2_Specie_1_Média.1    360 non-null    float64       
 13  Specie_2_Total.1             360 non-null    int64         
 14  Specie_3_Specie_2_Point_1.2  360 non-null    int64         
 15  Specie_3_Specie_2_Point_2.2  360 non-null    int64         
 16  Specie_3_Specie_2_Point_3.2  360 non-null    int64         
 17  Specie_3_Specie_2_Point_4.2  360 non-null    int64         
 18  Specie_3_Specie_2_Média.2    360 non-null    float64       
 19  Specie_3_Total.2             360 non-null    int64         
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(3), int64(15), object(1)
memory usage: 56.4+ KB
```

Comment: Why not just use a `MultiIndex` here? i.e. consider using the `header` parameter of `read_excel`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your table starts at the cell `A0`, you can try this :

```
df = pd.read_excel(
    "/content/drive/MyDrive/Pollens.xlsx",
    sheet_name="Jun", index_col=[0, 1], header=[0, 1]
)

df = df.rename_axis(index=["Data", "Hour"])
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f"{x[0]}_{x[1]}")

df = df.reset_index() # optional ?
```